# How to track Indian Mutual Funds using Google Sheets and update the price automatically

Tags: google-sheets

Looking to manage the mutual fund portfolio, and automatically update the price so the portfolio always shows the correct information.

I have tried to use Google sheet functions like

```
INDEX
SPLIT
VLOOKUP
IMPORTDATA
```

---

```
=IMPORTDATA("https://www.amfiindia.com/spages/NAVAll.txt")
=INDEX(SPLIT(VLOOKUP(A2&amp;"*",NAV!$A$1:$A$20501,1,false),";"),,5)
```

The outcome of this is to create a portfolio with an automated price update.

Answer (score 14):

You can easily use [GOOGLEFINANCE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093281?hl=en) APIs to do this. Suppose you want to track price of **[SBI Magnum Taxgain Scheme Direct Growth](https://www.sbimf.com/en-us/equity-schemes/sbi-magnum-taxgain-scheme)**.

You can do this in the following steps:

1. Go to [Google Finance](https://www.google.com/finance).
2. Get the Google Finance Ticker symbol or Stock Id for the fund. For example:
   [MUTF_IN:SBI_MAGN_TAX_VQNUL5](https://www.google.com/search?biw=1440&bih=821&tbm=fin&sxsrf=ACYBGNTlGhnCvpknjHAVLeMBX0ifQJTH8w%3A1576925785383&ei=Wfr9Xav5FteX4-EPjqSm-As&stick=H4sIAAAAAAAAAONgecRowS3w8sc9YSn9SWtOXmPU5OIKzsgvd80rySypFJLmYoOyBKX4uXj10_UNDZPKC82yLJKNeAAGSbDjPQAAAA&q=MUTF_IN%3A%20SBI_MAGN_TAX_VQNUL5&oq=sbi%20tax&gs_l=finance-immersive.1.0.81l3.1773.9844.0.11432.11.9.2.0.0.0.157.869.0j7.7.0....0...1.1.64.finance-immersive..2.7.647....0.XVvxPLwhaao#scso=_Zfr9XYzNMO-H4-EP86OaoAM7:0) for **SBI Magnum Taxgain Scheme Direct Growth**.
3. In a new [Google Sheet](https://sheets.new) use the following method to get current price of the MF.

   ```
   =GOOGLEFINANCE("MUTF_IN:SBI_MAGN_TAX_VQNUL5")
   ```

For example see:

1. [Medium Article](https://medium.com/@rishabhagarwal1911/create-a-real-time-portfolio-tracker-using-google-sheets-14f5637d0f50)
2. [video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ditv6tOOb0s)
3. [sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-fc0krGZcZIDUT_5Ysuy2dHN7rP069HYTzK_jL2qMxM/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Yes, but now Google Finance has become part of search, finding code has become difficult.  The way I tried is more or less automated.

Comment: It is simple to find codes. Just find it here: https://www.google.com/finance. See the medium article. https://medium.com/@rishabhagarwal1911/create-a-real-time-portfolio-tracker-using-google-sheets-14f5637d0f50

Comment: Google Finance does not update the NAV quickly, today is Tuesday, and google still shows data of Friday. :(

Answer (score 4):

Most of the stocks and mutual funds are available via Google Finance API which [Rishabh's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59435693/7775276) explains clearly.

But Google finance doesn't have data for many Indian mutual funds like Axis Blue Chip Direct plan - Growth, Parag Parikh Flexi Cap Fund Direct Plan-Growth, etc.

[Suresh's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55322058/7775276) is a different yet effective way to add NAV and other details into google sheets but that formula is outdated and it no longer works in google sheets. So, I am answering this question with the new tested approach.

Steps to get the NAV for any mutual fund not present in Google Finance

- As Suresh mentioned, create two sheets. One for portfolio and the other for NAV
- In the first cell of the NAV sheet, enter the formula as

  =IMPORTDATA("https://www.amfiindia.com/spages/NAVAll.txt")
- Now, search for the mutual fund, I'm taking Axis BlueChip fund direct growth as an example.

[Have a look at this image of Axis BlueChip direct plan growth mutual fund in NAV sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tLTKL.png)

- Note the row number for the mutual fund and in our case, it is **5507**
- Notice how the value is separated by **";"** delimiter and we need to get NAV which is on 5th position (or column if separated by a delimiter)
- To get the NAV value extracted from the specified row number of NAV sheet in the portfolio one, do the following

  =INDEX(SPLIT(NAV!$A$5507,";"),5)

Breaking down,

> **NAV!A$5507**: It means, we're extracting row number 5507 from the NAV sheet

> **SPLIT(NAV!$A$5507,";")**: Since, the delimiter is ";", we're splitting it on ";" which will give us 5 columns (If you're confused, look at NAV sheet data again. There are a total of six fields Scheme Code, ISIN Div Payout/ ISIN Growth, ISIN Div Reinvestment, Scheme Name, Net Asset Value, Date)

> **=INDEX(SPLIT(NAV!$A$5507,";"),5)**: After splitting, we're choosing the 5th column which is NAV and that's how the above function works and we get the NAV value of the fund automatically.

- Once, we get the NAV value, we can add the quantity and buy avg value of our stock/mutual fund in another column of the portfolio sheets
- Then, with a simple operation, we can get the total value of our investment in sheets.

For example,

> =(E6-C6)*B6

- Cell E2 : Updated NAV price
- cell C2 : Buy average price
- Cell B2 : Quantity

I'd like to acknowledge my friend [Abhilash](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8430165/abhilash?tab=profile) who taught me to manage my stock portfolio by Google Sheets.

Comment: Nice answer! It helped me. Just to add, you can pass delimiter ";" in the IMPORTDATA function itself like =IMPORTDATA("https://www.amfiindia.com/spages/NAVAll.txt", ";") and the sheet will have multiple columns for that data. This way you would not need to do INDEX and SPLIT.

Answer (score 3):

Create a spreadsheet on Google Spreadsheets.  Name the spreadsheet as you need.

Let us create a sheet and name the sheet as "NAV".  This sheet will hold all the latest NAV and will be updated with the latest price automatically.  Let us visit this sheet later for automating the price update.

Now, let us create a new sheet, call it "Portfolio".
Create columns in the 1st row as follows:

```
AMFI Scheme ID
Account Number
AMC
Scheme Name 
Unit Balance 
Cost - Dividends 
Value 
Returns  
Return (%) 
AV Cost / Unit 
NAV 
NAV Date
```

Let us shift the tab to "NAV".  In the column, A1 enter the formula as

```
=IMPORTDATA("https://www.amfiindia.com/spages/NAVAll.txt")
```

This will update the NAV automatically and we will use this data to update information in our portfolio.  This will have the following columns now:

```
Scheme Code
ISIN Div Payout / ISIN Growth
ISIN Div Reinvestment
Scheme Name
Net Asset Value
Date
```

Now find the scheme you have invested in from the NAV tab and get the Scheme Code and copy to AMFI Scheme ID column on "Portfolio" sheet.  Similarly, you can copy the Scheme Name.

Get your statement from the AMC and update the Unit Balance, Cost - Dividends columns.

In the "Portfolio" sheet enter the formula against NAV

```
=INDEX(SPLIT(VLOOKUP(A2&amp;"*",NAV!$A$1:$A$20501,1,false),";"),,5)
```

In the "Portfolio" sheet enter the formula against NAV Date

```
=INDEX(SPLIT(VLOOKUP(A2&amp;"*",NAV!$A$1:$A$20501,1,false),";"),,6)
```

- Value column is the product of Units x NAV
- Returns are Value-(Cost-dividends)
- Return % is Returns / (Cost-dividends)
- AV Cost / Unit is (Cost-dividends) / Unit Balance

Now create a summary line in the bottom for Cost-Dividends, Value, Returns and Return %

Voila! Your portfolio will be updated automatically when you open the spreadsheet.  Just ensure you update unit balance and cost-dividends for accurate computations.

Answer (score 1):

### For the whole list of Schemes and their latest NAV try the following:

**First row:**

```
A1 = Scheme Code
B1 = ISIN Div Payout/ ISIN Growth
C1 = ISIN Div Reinvestment
D1 = Scheme Name
E1 = Net Asset Value
F1 = Date
```

**In B2:** paste the following:

> =ArrayFormula(SPLIT(FILTER(IMPORTDATA("https://www.amfiindia.com/spages/NAVAll.txt"),isnumber(left(IMPORTDATA("https://www.amfiindia.com/spages/NAVAll.txt"),2)*1)=true,IMPORTDATA("https://www.amfiindia.com/spages/NAVAll.txt")<>""),";"))